# Doctrine - First letter is capital when exporting mysql

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Something very weird/unusual happen when I export my SQL from my localhost to my server. For some reason Doctrine wants the same table but with the first letter being a capital letter.

For example, I have a table called "cart". It's always been that, never changed. On my localhost, the entity loads without any problem. I upload my Symfony2 projects, when I load my cart entity, doctrine throws an error saying "Cart" doesn't exist. If I change the table name to "Cart" it works.

It's the second project that this happen. Did anyone experience the same issue? If yes how did you solve it?

---

The error message is :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'gentleme_pa2.Product' doesn't exist

And the annotation is :

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table('product')
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly? Also, how have you defined the entity; show the annotations and class name. What is the file name / path for the `cart` PHP file?\

Comment: --- never mind I will put it in the answer with the annotation

Comment: Here I have updated it with the example of my table Product.

Comment: I'm surprised that incorrect annotation isn't being flagged

Comment: Oh my god, I've just realized it's wrong. Yes indeed stupid mistake thanks for pointing it out -- This is what happen when you work 12+ hours straight. Let's take a nap :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your entity make sure you are using:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cart")
 */
class Cart
{
...
}
```

Comment: same problem above does not fix, still looking for uppercase table name ?